Using custom CSS for Firefox file: directory listing
Firefox uses built-in CSS from a stylesheet named dirListing.css when it generates a directory listing. I want to customize the view of the page that FF generates. I made changes, but I can't save anything back to dirListing.css. How do I save changes permanently?
I tried changing the file in different places, through "inspector" and "style editor." I expected the changes to be saved automatically.

You're not supposed to change your browser's local files; these are managed by the developers of that browser and not you. Changing local files might corrupt your browser entirely. It would be better to "add" custom styling to the specific web page you're using to view your local files or request this as a feature to whoever created the app you use to browse files via a webbrowser.

I was not able to completely test this answer but you might be able to modify Firefox generated pages using userContent.css.
Placing some CSS such as the following inside of it.
@-moz-document regexp("^(file|chrome|resource).*/$"){
  body{ background: #323427 !important }
}

Link to modifying userContent below
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/contributors-guide-firefox-advanced-customization

You need to verify that the contents of the main frame are a directory listing, then inject the style. Two frameworks that allow you to do that are user scripts (using a script manager) or web extensions.
( function () {
  'use strict';

  var
    style = document.createElement( 'style' ),
    text = 'body { border: 1px solid black; }'; // change to whatever you really want

  // if the main frame has a file: URI and loads dirListing.css
  // it's pretty safe to assume it's a directory listing
  if ( location.protocol === 'file:' && document.querySelector(
    'link[ href = "chrome://global/skin/dirListing/dirListing.css" ]'
  ) ) {
    style.textContent = text;
    document.head.appendChild( style );
  }
} () );

You can test the code by running it in the devtools console.
If you use a script manager (which is itself a web extension), you can maintain the CSS text in the script manager itself. If you make a web extension, you would make this script the content script and (ideally) maintain the CSS in an options page (on about:addons) that keeps the CSS in extension storage.
The most popular script managers are Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey. There are probably others. (Disclaimer: I don't use any of them. This answer is not an endorsement.)
For a web extension, the manifest would look something like:
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Answer",
  "description": "Answer a Stack Overflow question",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'none'; object-src 'none'",
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "answer@nanigashi.stackoverflow"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "matches": [ "file:///*" ]
  } ],
  "options_ui": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "page": "options.htm"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ]
}

where content.js is the script. options.htm is the panel for about:addons (outside the scope of this question) to maintain the CSS. The storage permission gives access to the browser.storage API to store and retrieve the CSS.
